# Get javax.sql.DataSource from javax.persistence.EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa

I have to deal with an API which need to be provided a DataSource as a parameter. The problem is I'm accessing it from a context that provides an EntityManager or a PersistentContext, which do not appear to expose any DataSource through its methods.
How is it possible to programmatically retrieve the underlying DataSource from an EntityManager ?

Comment: which jpa implementation have you used? How did you get your EM? eg. via some framework like Spring  ?

Comment: I use Hibernate as JPA implementation. I'm not using Spring and I get my EM by annotating a property with @EntityManager. In my case, using Spring IOC is not a option.

Comment: You can try to inject DataSource by @Resource annotation or can get it through JNDI lookup.

Comment: Thanks Nayan. I tried something like          

    *@Resource(name = "jdbc/...")
    private DataSource dataSource;*

and it's working. I think it's the more elegant way to resolve my problem.comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is injecting datasource this way :

```
@Resource(name = "jdbc/...")
private DataSource dataSource;
```

and then providing the datasource as an argument to the API.

Comment: But only inside a container. How to retrieve it in a CLI application? (yes you can have jee inside CLI applications)